# JavaScriptSerializer doesn't serialize DynamicJsonObject properly

Tags: c#, json

I have a DynamicJsonObject like:

```
var obj = new DynamicJsonObject();
obj.Field1 = "field1";
obj.Field2 = "field2";
```

I need the obj's json string. I tried using `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var json = JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

But the result is always `json == '{}'`

Is there a workaround for this? preferably not using third party libraries

Comment: Just use an anonymous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but I've found a simple way to do this by using `System.Web.Helpers.Json`.
So, my code looks like this:

```
string json = Json.Encode(obj);
```

I cannot use an anonymous object, because I don't create `obj`, it is provided in the DynamicJsonObject 'format' already.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom converter to JavaScriptSerializer. In System.Web.Helpers one already exists but is internal - you can use the following code to register it:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJavaScriptConverter, System.Web.Helpers");
var converter = (JavaScriptConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { converter });

var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

or copy code from [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1db9afa47f02#src/System.Web.Helpers/DynamicJavaScriptConverter.cs)